# Get package name/ID in the Log method from an SSIS Custom Logging Provider

Tags: ssis

I have a custom SSIS logging provider to push logs from SSIS processes to a custom logging service. The logging configuration is in the package level.

Process:
1. In the OpenLog, I create an operation ID to the log, to be assigned to the existing logging service.
2. When the log method is executed, I log an event in the existing logging service as a child of the operation created in the OpenLog method.

Everything works fine, however a new SSIS package was created with child packages. Therefore, now I have multiple Operation ID's, and since the packages are executed in parallel, I have to use the proper Operation ID to each log.

Problem? The Log method doesn't provide the current package. The SourceID provides the component ID, but not the Package ID.

Is there a way (from the API) to retrieve the package logging an entry?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1):

So far SSIS doesn't provide a direct way to access the package name or id inside the custom log provider.

What you can do is enable the package logging through the custom log provider and provide the package name as **Configuration** property to custom provider.

Then you can access **ConfigString** property within the custom log provider methods and create an event source using it.

In your case you can create a one custom provider for both parent and child and provide different names for configuration property.